# Telemetrics datasets for vehicles

Tags: data-request

I need telemetrics dataset for vehicles, to categorize riskiness of drivers based on their driving behaviour. I have already looked into kaggle's AXA Telemtrics challenge, unfortunately kaggle has removed the data.

Does anyone has the link to AXA data or any other vehicle telemetrics data?